# XSLT for segmenting XML

Tags: xslt, select, nodes

I have an XML that goes like this:

```
<company>
    <employee name="john"/>
    <employee name="sarah"/>
    <employee name="kim"/>
    <employee name="karl"/>
    <employee name="tom"/>
    <employee name="jim"/>
    <employee name="sandy"/>
</company>
```

How can I use a XSLT template for selecting just the first n nodes, 3 for example, so I can get:

```
<company>
    <employee name="john"/>
    <employee name="sarah"/>
    <employee name="kim"/>
</company>
```

In Oxygen XML editor, I can use the following XPath to achieve that:

```
/company/employee[position() < (last() - count(/company/employee)+4)]
```

but I really need to use XSLT in this case
Thanks for your help

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and extremely short solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use a XSLT template for
>   selecting just the first n nodes, 3
>   for example, so I can get:
>
> ```
> <company> 
>     <employee name="john"/> 
>     <employee name="sarah"/> 
>     <employee name="kim"/> 
> </company>
> ```

**The short answer**: By knowing just a little bit XPath and XSLT.

**Complete(but still short) answer**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="employee[position() > 3]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<company>
    <employee name="john"/>
    <employee name="sarah"/>
    <employee name="kim"/>
    <employee name="karl"/>
    <employee name="tom"/>
    <employee name="jim"/>
    <employee name="sandy"/>
</company>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<company>
   <employee name="john"/>
   <employee name="sarah"/>
   <employee name="kim"/>
</company>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) is used** to copy every node "as-is".
2. **There is just one specific template overriding the identity template**. It matches any `employee` element with position in the node-list greater than 3. This template has an empty body, effectively discarding the matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

> I can use the following XPath to
>   achieve that:
>
> ```
> /company/employee[position() < (last() - count(/company/employee)+4)]
> ```

Do note that here `last()` is equal to `count(/company/employee)`, so this will be reduce to:

```
/company/employee[4 > position()]
```

In a pattern you could have:

```
<xsl:template match="employee[4 > position()]">    
...
</xsl:template>
```

The same with parametrization (Remenber you can't use parameter reference in XSLT 1.0 patterns):

```
<xsl:param name="pTop" select="3"/>    

<xsl:template match="employee">    
   <xsl:if test="$pTop >= position()">    
   ...
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="company/employee[position() &lt; 3]">
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

This might work with `<template select=....` too but i'm not sure.